# Выполнить операцию вычитания, когда есть NULL-значения,SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

есть скрипт

```
drop table if exists tmpStorage;
drop table if exists tmpRepeal;

create TEMP table tmpStorage AS
select m.id, m.name, sum(s.amount) as "total" from storage s 
inner join materials m on m.id = s.material_id group by s.material_id, m.id, m.name order by m.name;

create TEMP table tmpRepeal AS
select m.id, m.name, sum(amount) as "repeal"  from repeal r 
inner join materials m on m.id = r.material_id group by r.material_id, m.id, m.name order by m.name;

select s.name, s.total, r.repeal from tmpStorage s
left join tmpRepeal r on s.id = r.id;
```

он возвращает таблицу вида

```
Название;Общее кол-во;Списание;
тов1    ;   5        ;   2
тов2    ;   10       ;   NULL
```

необходимо получить фактическое значение, т.е. общее кол-во - списание, прописал последний select по-другому:

```
select s.name, (s.total-r.repeal) as "available" from tmpStorage s
left join tmpRepeal r on s.id = r.id;
```

Но тогда оно возвращает `NULL`, если справа `NULL`, а (если смотреть на пример), то мне нужно чтобы вернуло 10. 
Идея как-то может заменить NULL на 0.

Comment: используйте функцию `coalesce()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо [Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/mike), который посоветовал:

> используйте функцию coalesce()